How to invoke a .bat file with elevated privileges from MATLAB
The goal invoke .bat files with administrative privilege from MATLAB.   The Windows user account is a member of the administrators group, however, invoking the date command to change the system date / time returns insufficient privilege and seems to require an "administrative" terminal.
I am starting with the Andrew Janke solution and would like to run a .bat file that requires administrative privilege (date command is in the .bat file).   I have successfully run simple batch files with commands known not to require privileges.
The crux of the said Janke solution is:
startInfo = `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`('cmd.exe', sprintf('/c "%s"', batFile));

Is there an argument that be added to modify cmd.exe or elsewhere in the parentheses owned by System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.
What is the syntax to elevate the privilege of call to cmd.exe?
My Google search failed to turn up a simple solution. What I did find seemed to be on the right track but I would prefer a simple argument for the said function: How to start a Process as administrator mode in C#

Well the first thing you should be aware of, if running cmd.exe with /C or /K arguments is that all of those arguments should be enclosed within a single set of doublequotes. For example: %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "Arg1 "Arg 2" Arg3". The outer quote pair are removed by cmd.exe. You will note that nested doublequotes do not usually require additional escaping. It is however best practice to doublequote each individual argument, and where necessary, ask the called command or utility to handle any required removal of those doublequotes.

@Compo  Thank you for taking the time to edit the question and providing a helpful comment.   Can you clarify why I would use /C or  /K?   /C /K Reference: https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html.    If that somehow elevates privilege, I would encourage you to post an answer.

Does your shown cmd.exe command use either /C or /K? Even if you aren't specifying one, /C is default. Therefore, what I've told you is the correct syntax for what you've shown in your question, not an answer to your question. Of course, I'd want to know if you've considered not running cmd.exe directly, and perhaps using runas.exe to launch the batch file by name.

@Compo   I think you are indicating that /C is invoked and that the subsequent arguments passed to the function must in double quotes For example: cmd.exe  /C "myBatchfile.bat".   I think this is what sprintf does.    That being said, runas.exe is new to me and seems to be a promising substitute for cmd.exe?  https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html    Not having any luck or maybe I missed something.  Again, Thanks

Well technically, as previously mentioned, it is good practice to doublequote arguments, that could be %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C ""P:\athTo\myBatchfile.bat""; (one set for the /C argument and one for the batch file name).

@Compo Thanks for the clarifying example with the double quotes.   Why is it best practice to use the double quotes?   Just curious.

You can configure your batch script to automatically elevate itself when executed, ensuring you never "forget" it needs sufficient privileges for its operations.
Place this code as early as possible in your batch script (usually after @echo off, setlocal, and a basic argument check, so elevation isn't requested unnecessarily, such as when only displaying help syntax):
REM Check admin mode and auto-elevate if required
openfiles > NUL 2>&1 || (
    REM Not elevated - perform elevation
    echo createObject^("Shell.Application"^).shellExecute "%~dpnx0", "%*", "", "runas">"%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    goto :eof
)
del /s /q "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs" > NUL 2>&1


Explanation:
The basic idea is to check if the script is already elevated using a command like openfiles, in "mute mode", which requires elevated privileges to run. If it fails, the || operator triggers the auto-elevation sequence.

Creating VBScript Dynamically:

A temporary VBScript file is created on-the-fly. It uses shellExecute with the runas parameter to relaunch the batch script with elevation.
%~dpnx0 represents the current batch script, while %* forwards any original command-line arguments.


Executing Elevation:

The VBScript runs without elevation, but it prompts for elevation before executing the batch script.
The original batch exits immediately using goto :eof.


Returning to Elevated Script:

When the elevated batch restarts, the openfiles command succeeds, skipping the elevation block.
The temporary VBScript file is deleted, and the batch script proceeds in the elevated environment.




Limitation:
A major drawback of this method is that shellExecute does not allow waiting for the elevated process to finish. This means:

ShellExecute: Elevate easily but lose control over the batch script's execution.
Run: Control execution but cannot handle elevation automatically.

Workarounds:

Active Waiting:

Poll the process in a loop to check if it has completed, but this risks missing short-lived processes.


Advanced Win32 API:

Use more sophisticated solutions leveraging the Win32 API, which are more complex to implement in a batch script.



Unfortunately, a straightforward solution that combines automatic elevation and precise control isn't readily available in batch scripting.
